# Know where my friends are from my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, location, core-location

Is it possible to know in my app where some user from my list is located? I know it's possible technically if 2 users install the same app, e.g. instant messenger, with locating feature and allow it to use location API from the device.

Here is an example from Viber, marked with a red circle on the bottom right:

[image: Show my location]

But I wonder if it's possible for one user to have an app, where she can access information about her friends, e.g. from Find My Friends app on iOS?

If not from the Find My Friends, then it would be fine to ask the other side to allow me to see where he is somehow. So, as a result, one person would confirm that she is ok to share the location, not having to install the app, and the other one would access this from his app.

Comment: On iOS you cannot access other apps, apps can only access files within it's own sandbox. About other apps like 'Find my friends' you will need access to their API and web service if you want to request the user location user that app. And my guess is that is not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This can be answered by an explanation only. No small-code can solve this.

One way to do this is to `share a URL string` (a URL string can be created for this in app which must include your location coordinates) with location data from your app and send it to your friend. When your friend opens this URL in any `browser`, it connects with your `server` (yes, you will have to implement the *other side* on a server) which evaluates this URL to display relevant UI. You will use the location data on server end to display the UI (like on a `map` or in `text` form).